# jQuery: how to fix the multiple occurrence rises in a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, click, live

I made my first jQuery plugin attempt, but I have this problem/bug which I don't know how to work around it in a plugin.

Here is the link to see the problem - [my first plugin](http://nano-visions.net/dump/).

Here is how you can get the bug out:

1. Click on the the **first** 'DELETE' link, then you see a popup, click 'OK', then you see a form is loaded, then click 'No'.
2. You can repeat the process no.1 as many times as you want.
3. Then you see the bug when you click on the **second** 'DELETE' - you will get a repeated popups depends on how many times you repeated the process no.1

So multiple occurrence happens when I hit the 'No' button on the loaded form.

But I don't know how to get rid of these multiple occurrences - **it should only occur once** (the popup should only happen once, when you click the **second** 'DELETE').

Here is the entire html and jQuery code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.delete-uploaded').pluginname({
        deleteItem:     '.item-uploaded', 
        deleteParent:   '.items-uploaded',
        wrapperParent:  '.upload'
    });
});


// You need an anonymous function to wrap around your function to avoid conflict
(function($){

    // Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({ 

        // This is where you write your plugin's name
        pluginname: function(options) {

            //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                deleteItem:     '.item-listed', 
                deleteParent:   '.items-listed',
                wrapperParent:  '.upload',
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            // return this.click(function(){ // original
            // "this" is already a jQuery object: 
            // When you create the click function you can assign that element to a variable and reference it within:
            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                var o = options;
                var target_delete = $(this).parents(o.deleteItem); // The item for deletion, such as item held in li 
                var parent_delete = $(this).parents(o.deleteParent); // The parent that hold delete item, such as ul > li
                var wrapper_parent = $(this).parents(o.wrapperParent); // The wrapper that hold the parent, such as div > ul > li
                var target_loadin = $(this).parent();
                var target_html = $(this).parent().html();
                var path_load = $(this).attr('href');
                var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
                //alert(class_name);
                alert($cm.selector);

                // Load the delete form.
                target_loadin.load( path_load, function(){

                    // When the yes button is triggered.
                    $("input[type=submit][name=yes]").click(function(){

                        // Get the path from attribute of action in the form.
                        var path_post = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
                        //alert(path_post);



                        // Post the form.
                        $.post(path_post, $(this).serialize(), function(xml){

                            // Procees the form output.
                            //process_delete_uploaded(xml);
                        });

                        // Slide up the deleted target.
                        target_delete.slideUp('fast', function() {

                            // Remove its divs completely
                            target_delete.remove();
                            //alert($('li',parent_delete).length);

                            // Count how many items are left behind         
                            if($('li',parent_delete).length == 0)
                            {
                                $('.binder-row',wrapper_parent).css({
                                    borderBottom: '0px solid #999', 
                                    padding: '0px 0px 0px 0px'
                                });
                            }

                        });

                        return false;
                    });


                    // When the no/cancel button is triggered.
                    $("input[type=button][name=no]").click(function(){

                        // Return the html
                        target_loadin.html(target_html);

                        // Reload the delete function
                        $($cm.selector).pluginname({
                            deleteItem:     o.deleteItem, 
                            deleteParent:   o.deleteParent,
                            wrapperParent:  o.wrapperParent
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
                });

                return false;

            });

        }
    });

//pass jQuery to the function, 
//So that we will able to use any valid Javascript variable name 
//to replace "$" SIGN. But, we'll stick to $ (I like dollar sign: ) )       
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the html,

```
<!-- upload c1-->
<div class="upload upload-image">

    <!-- binder-background -->
    <div class="binder-background target-toggler">

        <!-- binder-row -->
        <div class="binder-row">
            <a href="#" class="btn-upload btn-upload-image" name="image" rel="#" >Upload</a>
            <div class="status-upload status-upload-image"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- binder-row -->

        <!-- binder-row -->
        <div class="binder-row">

            <!-- items-uploaded -->
            <ul class="sort items-uploaded items-uploaded-image">

                <!-- item-uploaded -->
                <li id="item_29" class="item-uploaded">

                    <!-- item-uploaded-info -->
                    <div class="item-uploaded-info">

                        <span><a href="form_image_delete.php?img_id=29" class="delete-uploaded">DELETE</a></span>
                        <h4>9419_169881528011_783228011_3657915_407804_n_20110330221805.jpg</h4>

                    </div>
                    <!-- item-uploaded-info -->

                </li>
                <!-- item-uploaded -->


                <!-- item-uploaded -->
                <li id="item_30" class="item-uploaded">

                    <!-- item-uploaded-info -->
                    <div class="item-uploaded-info">

                        <span><a href="form_image_delete.php?img_id=30" class="delete-uploaded">DELETE</a></span>
                        <h4>69285_4159_1_06789134_webphotoscopy2_20110330221817.jpg</h4>

                    </div>
                    <!-- item-uploaded-info -->

                </li>
                <!-- item-uploaded -->


            </ul>
            <!-- items-uploaded -->



        </div>
        <!-- binder-row -->

    </div>
    <!-- binder-background -->

</div>
<!-- upload c1-->
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
// When the no/cancel button is triggered.
$("input[type=button][name=no]",target_loadin).click(function(){

    // The string will become ojects after spliting it into pieces with .split(),
    // so you must turn the object into string again with .toString().
    var selector_current = $cm.selector.split(' ').slice(-1).toString(); 

    // Return the html
    target_loadin.html(target_html);

    // Reload the delete function
    target_loadin.find(selector_current).pluginname({
        deleteItem:     o.deleteItem, 
        deleteParent:   o.deleteParent,
        wrapperParent:  o.wrapperParent
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicking `` `no' `` you are reloading the plugin for all `.delete-uploaded` elements (you are using `$($cm.selector)` = `$('.delete-uploaded')` not only the one clicked.

But, if we try to use `target_loadin.find($cm.selector)`, when calling the plugin for only the clicked element, the selector changes to `'parent() .delete-uploaded'` which is not valid!!!

One solution is to build a selector that will not change for the clicked element:

Replace:

```
alert($cm.selector);
```

by

```
if($($cm.selector).length > 1)
    curr_selector = $($cm.selector+':eq('+$($cm.selector).index($(this))+')')
                    .selector;
else
    curr_selector = $cm.selector;
alert(curr_selector);
```

and in the `'no' function` use `curr_selector`:

```
// When the no/cancel button is triggered.
$("input[type=button][name=no]").click(function(){

    // Return the html
    target_loadin.html(target_html);

    // Reload the delete function
    (curr_selector).pluginname({
        deleteItem:     o.deleteItem, 
        deleteParent:   o.deleteParent,
        wrapperParent:  o.wrapperParent
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: @manji: thanks for the answer. I have tried it out with your answer but then a new bug/ problem occurs - here is the another page to see it. http://nano-visions.net/dump/index2.php thanks.

Comment: the bug happens when you click the 'no' button at the second time on the first 'DELETE' link.

Comment: try using `target_loadin.find($cm.selector)[0]`

Comment: thanks manji for the edit. I also worked out a solution, have a look on my edit :-) thanks so much for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

.load method always loads a complete document, so there are multiple calls to methods (exponential rise). There is a simple (but not pretty) workaround - put your javascript code inside the main html document.